# PHP - Problema com retorno de busca INNER JOIN com GROUP BY!

Tags: php, mysql

Então, Tenho 3 tabela:

```
user:
    | ID | NOME | SOBRENOME |
    | 01 | Igor | Ferreira  |
    | 02 | João | Henrique  |
    | 03 | Rose | Beltão    |

following:
    | ID | user1_id | user2_id |
    | 01 |    01    |    02    |  User 1 > Segue User 2
    | 02 |    02    |    01    |     -- User 2 > Segue User 1
    | 03 |    01    |    03    |  User 1 > Segue User 3
    | 04 |    03    |    01    |     -- User 3 > Segue User 1
    | 05 |    03    |    02    |  User 3 > Segue User 2
    | 06 |    02    |    03    |     -- User 2 > Segue User 3

chat:
    | ID | user1 | user2 |      mensagem      |       data       |
    | 01 |   02  |   03  | ola Rose.          | 30/07/2015 08:25 |  De João > Para Rose
    | 02 |   03  |   02  | Oi João, como tas? | 30/07/2015 08:28 |  De Rose > Para João
    | 03 |   02  |   03  | Estou bem, e você? | 30/07/2015 08:29 |  De João > Para Rose
    | 04 |   01  |   02  | Rose você esta ai? | 30/07/2015 09:11 |  De Igor > Para Rose
```

Em uma div estou listando os usuários que ambos se seguem e quem traz a mensagem mais recente de acordo com a tabela chat:

```
$sqln = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT
                                u.id,
                                u.foto,
                                u.username,
                                u.nome_us,
                                u.sobrenome_us,
                                u.tell
                            FROM users u
                                RIGHT JOIN following f
                                    ON f.user1_id = '$id'
                                INNER JOIN chat c
                                    ON ((c.id_de = '$id' and c.id_para = f.user2_id) or (c.id_de = f.user2_id and c.id_para = '$id'))
                            WHERE
                                u.id = f.user2_id
                            GROUP BY 
                                u.id
                            ORDER BY
                                c.data DESC, c.hora DESC");
```

Porem se eu por a `GROUP BY u.id`, onde ele pega todas as mensagens de um usuário e joga numa unica caixa: 
[image: photo 1]
porem ele não ordena de acordo com as menagens mais recentes na tabela chat.

Agora se eu tirar a `GROUP BY u.id` ele lista realmente de acordo com as mais recentes, porem ele joga todas as mensagens sem querer saber de repetições: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver?? Fazer com que realmente liste de forma mais recente na tabela **chat** e que não seja com repetições em uma unica `div`?

Comment: os *prints* de código dificultam muito o entendimento da sua pergunta, se você criar um [fiddle SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/) com a sua estrutura de banco de dados e a consulta, e adicionar o link no texto da pergunta vai facilitar que os usuário possam dar uma boa resposta

Comment: @Sanção http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f0e/3/0 é isso...

Comment: O campo data é do tipo date?

Comment: @PedroQuezado seu SQLFiddle não está funcionando aqui... O link está correto?

Comment: Está sim @KaduAmaral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minha *query* pode estar um pouco complexa, mas foi o que consegui sem estar familiarizado com o sistema e modelagem.

```
SET @user = 2;

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    z.id, 
    u.nome_us,
    -- u.foto,
    -- u.username,
    u.sobrenome_us,
    -- u.tell,
    (SELECT `data` FROM chat 
     WHERE 
       (id_de = @user AND id_para = z.id) OR
       (id_para = @user AND id_de = z.id)
     ORDER BY `data` DESC LIMIT 1
     ) AS 'data'
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT x.id FROM (
        SELECT id_de AS id, `data`
        FROM chat WHERE id_para = @user LIMIT 20

        UNION DISTINCT

        SELECT DISTINCT id_para AS id, `data`
        FROM chat WHERE id_de = @user LIMIT 20
    ) AS x
  ) AS z
    INNER JOIN users u ON z.id = u.id
) AS j
  ORDER BY j.`data` DESC;
```

A *query* só retorna os dados do usuário e a data da última mensagem, caso queira também a última mensagem, pode fazer da mesma forma que foi buscada a data, utilizando uma *subquery*.

**Obs.:** Note que usei a variável do SQL na *query* `@user`, troque pela do PHP.

Comment: realmente deu resultado, porem não sei trabalhar com esse tipo de script.. teria como vc fazer o seu script retornar exatamente esses valores da tabela users para um while http://i.imgur.com/fp0IKTg.png .. não sei como retornar pelo seu código foi mau..

Comment: Esses campos são da tabela `users`? São os dados do seguidor?

Comment: Olha aqui @PedroQuezado http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f0e/36

Comment: kkk eu já fiz isso e pegou... muito obrigado mesmo @KaduAmaral

Answer (score -1):

Voce tem que fazer um select por fora agrupando por usuario e um select por dentro fazendo a ordenação. Desta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
  u.id AS idUsers,
  u.foto,
  u.username,
  u.nome_us,
  u.sobrenome_us,
  u.tell 
FROM
  users u 
  RIGHT JOIN following f 
    ON f.user1_id = '$id' 
  INNER JOIN chat c 
    ON (
      (
        c.id_de = '$id' 
        AND c.id_para = f.user2_id
      ) 
      OR (
        c.id_de = f.user2_id 
        AND c.id_para = '$id'
      )
    ) 
WHERE u.id = f.user2_id 
ORDER BY c.data DESC,
  c.hora DESC) AS mensagens
GROUP BY idUsers
```

Comment: continua sem dar o resultado certo ;(  @euler01